# Litle help in php and ajax filies

Tags: javascript, php

I got stuck when using ajax as primary request sender to php.

I was trying to send data to php file and then take that data to view in another file, but the problem is I don't know how to do it .

I tried

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "function.php");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        window.location = "view.php";
    }
}
ajax.send("a="+a+"&b="+b);
```

it locate `view.php` and I want to take contents that sent 
`function.php` and view it's contents in `view.php`.

That is where my problem occurs.

So, my question is **HOW TO TAKE THOSE CONTENTS**

Comment: use a simple form for that http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand the use of ajax... here you don't need ajax at all. Ajax is used to update/send content without refreshing the page. So if you want to pass data to a new php file, just pass the variables directly to view.php in your case.

For instance:

go to view.php?a=[your value]&b=[your value]

in view.php you can get the values:

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
```

and pass it to your function.php

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jquery** to **avoid** dealing with **browsers specifications** and also jquery is pretty **popular** and **simple** to use library

Assuming you are familiar with php and JavaScript

first you have to do all this work in you *www* or *htdocs* folder depending on the stack you are using whether it is XAMPP,WAMP or LAMP

let's say as an example we want to send post request to function.php file and that file should verify the existance of $_POST['username'] and return the length of username otherwise it returns 0

so the function.php file should be something like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    echo strlen($_POST['username']);
}else{
    echo 0;
}
```

and the view.php file is the file used to send post request and get the response and displays it in a #display div

so here is the content of view.php

```
// first you should include jquery 
// here is a cdn link  
// https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js
// or you can use a local jquery file it is up to you

<div id="display">
</div>


// here is the simple js code to send and get the data from function.php file

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// waiting for the document until it is ready to use 
$.post('function.php',{username:'myusername'},function(data){
  // data here is the returned data from the function.php file 
  $('#display').text('username length is : '+data);
});
});
</script>
```